# Is this an indirect object?

Tags: grammar, indirect-objects

"I stole a wallet from her"

I have always known indirect verbs to be "to" someone, can a direct object be taken "from" the indirect object?

Comment: No: the indirect object is characteristically associated with the semantic role of recipient, or beneficiary of something. The recipient in your example is "I", which has the syntactic role of subject. In any case preposition phrases (or the NP of the prep) can't be indirect objects, though they may have the same meaning. So, "wallet" is direct object and "from her" is just a complement not indirect object, of "stole".

Comment: "Indirect Object" is a term invented by grammarians -- and a term at the sharp edges of semantics and syntax at that -- and every grammarian has their own definitions of it, their own sense of its place in a theory, their own way of using it in composing grammars, and their own favorite languages they use it in describing; there is no ISO standard for grammatical terminology. It varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct objects are the entities in the sentence that are directly affected or acted upon by transitive verbs. So, here *a wallet* is the direct object of *stole* because it is the thing that *stole* is directly acting upon.

The indirect object, on the other hand, is someone or something that receives or is affected by the direct object. Consider the fallowing example:

> I stole **a wallet** for **her**.

*a wallet* here as is previously mentioned is the direct object of *stole*. *her* is the indirect object because it is the recipient of the direct object, in this case *a wallet*.

Now, let's turn things around a little bit and change *for* to *from*:

> I stole **a wallet** from **her**.

*a wallet* is still the direct object. Is *her* being somehow affected by the direct object? Yes, it is. So, then it must be the indirect object of the verb *stole*.

Does all this make sense to you?

Comment: Yes I agree with that. The only thing to say in addition is that in Latin, whilst *to* would require the dative case, *from* would take the ablative. But in English both are seen as indirect objects.

Comment: -1 "Her" is not indirect object in those examples for several reasons: (1) an indirect object is associated with the semantic role of recipient, or beneficiary of something. (2) "steal" is not a ditransitive verb like, say, "give", and hence does license (permit) an indirect object, e.g. _I gave her a wallet_ is fine, but *_I stole her a wallet_ is definitely non-standard; (3) NPs as core complements (objects) are related directly to the verb, but an NP as object of a preposition is only indirectly related, via the preposition, and hence is an 'oblique', not an object of the verb at all.

Comment: Just two points. Have you read Professor Lawler's comment above? And I am not persuaded that *I stole you a biscuit* is totally ungrammatical.

Comment: I didn't actually say that "I stole her a wallet" is ungrammatical - I said that it is non-standard. In any case, an indirect object is complement of a verb, not of a preposition, and that is an unarguable syntactic fact.

Comment: No, that's an arguable theoretical definition. One can treat prepositions as detachable crutches, as relational grammar or predicate calculus do; or one could simply append them to one side of an alternation like Dative. The benefactive case is interesting, though -- _cook_ is no more a three-place predicate than _steal_, but it allows _She cooked me a meal_ vs _She cooked a meal for me_ (i.e, Dative alternation), even though any sentence with a volitional subject can append a _for_ benefactive phrase (_She took the exam for me; She stayed up for me_). Most of them don't alternate.

Comment: In an example like _I ordered a copy for Sue_, the traditional account that "Sue" is indirect object seems to be based entirely on the fact that the semantic role (recipient or beneficiary) of "Sue" is the same as in _I ordered Sue a copy_. But "Sue" also has that role in the passive _Sue was sent a copy_, yet no one would want to say that it was indirect object here - it's clearly the subject. Grammar allows for varying alignments of sematic role and syntactic function - the latter must be assigned on the basis if syntactic properties, not semantic ones.

Comment: Further, there can be no plausible argument in favour of saying that in _I stole a wallet from her_, the role of indirect object can be assigned to "her". That is what the OP asked about, and the answer can only be no.

Comment: @WS2  In English dialects where *“I stole **you** a biscuit”* is permissible, I would take its *you* there to be the beneficiary of the theft, not its victim; is that what you meant? Privative verbs with pairs of objects historically took a variety of possible cases in their pairs in PIE’s children—including instrumental and genitive not just dat/acc. Spanish today can still take a dative in “robbing someone something”, but we have almost no examples in Modern English of what in Old and Middle English had been “privative datives”, though *“forbidding **someone** entrance”* might be one such.

Comment: @tchrist Yes that was what I meant. Equally *denying someone (e.g.) their rightful inheritance* is another.

Comment: I was wondering more if an indirect object had to be "given" or "received" or whatnot the direct object. If it just came down to a much simpler argument over where the indirect object would fit into the syntax, I would be fine. The problem is, because different languages have different syntaxes for them, it's a semantic issue related to the concept. I can say, "I am giving **him** negative twenty-five dollars," and "he" is still the indirect object. Because of this, could I say a semantically equivalent sentence while being syntactically different, "I am taking from him a dollar"?

Comment: I get that in English syntax, **her** in my original example was a prepositional object, but diverging from that, in an abstract sense, could a language possess "the recipient" of a verb that takes something away? Because, one definition I keep running into is that the verb indirectly effects the indirect object, and stealing person's wallet does sound like it qualifies for that.

Comment: For those who somehow think 'her' is not an indirect object as asked in the question, what exactly do you think it is instead?